# Use resource files instead of satellite assemblies

Tags: c#, installation, wix, windows-installer

We are using a .NET component that uses satellite assemblies for localization. However, if we want to create our own translations, we would have to send our translations or pay for the source code in order to get the Key File for signing.

Is it possible to load a .resources file in our main application, so that the localized strings are used by the component?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I didn't find a way to localize a strong-named assembly without its key, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537958/override-a-resource-from-standard-assembly-in-asp-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not to resign all assemblies?

Comment: This is probably the best solution for development. If you only want to use the components on one machine, you can also delay sign the satellite assemblies and turn off the validation for the components you want to localize. Thanks!