# My Model Error is removed if I am using Resource File

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5, resource-files, data-annotations

Hi I am using a model having

```
 [Range(1, 4, ErrorMessageResourceName = "NameRequiredError", ErrorMessageResourceType =typeof(Resources.PatientNotes))]
 public int ActionType { get; set; }
```

My Resource file  contains key as `NameRequiredError` and its value as "Name is required" but when I run I don't get any error and My Model State is valid but when I use

```
 [Range(1, 4)]
 public int ActionType { get; set; }
```

then it gives me proper error and `ModelState.IsValid` as `False`

The problem is only when I use separate project for resource file; otherwise it works well.

Comment: Are you sure your reference to your seperate resource file is correct?

Comment: Yes, I am just copying and Pasting That File Directly to another project.
I am just unable to locate

Comment: Take a look at the answers here, may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537958/override-a-resource-from-standard-assembly-in-asp-net